# ffmpeg parse error with bass audio filter and expression evaluation

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, equalizer, bass

I am trying to dynamically change the bass of an audio file as a function of time. For instance, say I would like to gradually increase the bass over a period of 5 seconds. The command I am using is

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.wav -af \
    "bass=g='if(lte(t,5),-20+(20/5)*t,0)':width_type=q:w=0.70" \
    out.wav
```

However I am receiving the error

```
[bass @ 0x19890c0] [Eval @ 0x7ffd8e143630] Unknown function in 't,5),-20+(20/5)*t,0)'
```

As a second attempt, I instead tried to use `min` instead of `lte`, the command being

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.wav -af \
    "bass=g='min(-20+20*t/5,0)':width_type=q:w=0.70" \
     out.wav
```

but got a slightly different error

```
[bass @ 0x263d040] [Eval @ 0x7fff0c8e7dc0] Invalid chars '(-20+20*t/5,0)' at the end of expression 'min(-20+20*t/5,0)'
```

Comment: gain only accepts numbers (float), not exprs.

Comment: @Gyan hmmmm I was afraid of that. So no way to have it change continuously with time? Also how did you know that? I had trouble finding it in the documentation.

Comment: I checked the source. Can't think of a filter that takes exprs for this.